JTA UserTransaction (with narayna implementation) rollback in standalone JPA+Hibernate application does not work
The following code snippet is in the main
try(EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()) {
        TestEntity e = new TestEntity();
        UserTransaction tx = com.arjuna.ats.jta.UserTransaction.userTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(e);
        tx.rollback();
    }

It is expected to be rollback but the given e is persisted to the database. The persistence works probably because of my configuration in persistence.xml
    <properties>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/test"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.charset_name" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="JBossTS"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class" value="jta"/>
    </properties>

The transaction-type of persistence-unit is RESOURCE_LOCAL, which means transaction is locally-managed without involvement of DataSource and jndi look-up. But in such way the narayna 's initialized UserTransaction seems not be aware of the database connection of the EntityManager instance, thus does not know the transaction controlled by the EntityManager
Question : but what is the resolution for making the rollback work properly?

I guess you either need to start the transaction before creating the entity manager,
Or call entityManager.joinTransaction()
